# Eigenvalue and finite difference equation

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences, eigenfunctions

I am given the fllowing problem:

> Find the solution of the eigenvalue problem $$ y'' + \lambda y =0$$ with $y(0)=y(1)=0$
>
> Let $h=\frac{1}{N}$. The FD discretization for the problem writes $$y_{n+1} - 2 y_n + y_{n-1} + \lambda_h h^2 y_n = 0 \quad (\star)$$ with $y_0=y_N=0$.
>
> *Since the components of the eigenvectors are the values of the eigenfunctions in nodes*
> $x = nh$, study the convergence of the eigenvalues $\lambda_h$ and estimate the error.

---

My attempt:

First of all $y(x)=\sin(k \pi x)$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, from the last *italic* sentence, I know that $$y_n = y(x_n)=y(nh) = \sin(k \pi n h)$$

Therefore, plugging these relation for $y_n$ in $(\star)$, I find:

$$\lambda_h = \frac{2}{h^2} \bigl ( 1-\cos(k \pi h) \bigr)$$

Now, honestly, I don't know how to answer the question: it's clear that since the numerator is bounded by $2$, as $h \rightarrow 0$ the $\lambda_h$ diverges. But I don't know if I can stop here.

Comment: I think you don't need finite differences here. Distinguish the cases $\lambda = 0, \lambda > 0$ and $\lambda < 0$ and plug in the boundary conditions in the general solutions, respectively.

Comment: It was the text of the exam the part about FD. Anyway, for $\lambda \leq 0$ there is no eigenfunction...

Comment: Does it really diverge?

Comment: @user619894 right, I'm stupid. As $h \rightarrow 0$, it goes to $k^2 \pi ^2$. I think this answers the convergence part. What about the error?

Comment: @user619894 Am I still wrong?

Comment: You need to compare $\lambda$ to $\lambda_h$

Comment: Right. $\lambda = - k^2 \pi ^2$. Then I expand, for $h$ in a neigbourhood of $0$ $$|\lambda - \lambda_h| $$

I obtain $|\lambda - \lambda_h| = \mathcal{O}(h^4) $, so the error decays as a power of $4$. 

Does this answer the question in the correct way?

Comment: @user619894 could you confirm my last comment?

Comment: I believe it is O(h^2)

Comment: True, I forgot to divide by $h^2$. Thanks for the check.